# When should I use "now" and "by now"?

Tags: adverbs, prepositional-phrases

1. The case is closed now.
2. The case is closed by now.
3. The case has been closed by now.

What exactly is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first sentence makes grammatical sense.

You would use 'by now' if you are talking about a hypothetical statement.

So for instance

> The case 'should' have been closed by now.

In each of your three examples, the case has been closed, so you would just use 'now'.

Comment: Thanks Gary. What difference do you see between "He will be happy by midnight" and "He will be happy at midnight" ?

Comment: Hi 'by midnight' suggests that there are going to be something happening between now and midnight that will make the person happy. 'at midnight' suggests that he will be happy precisely 'at midnight'.

Comment: Thank you gary sir. 1. Does "happy by midnight" suggest he will also be happy before midnight or does it say he will be happy only at midnight?  2.   By the time I came, my friend had prepared the dinner. Does it say the action of preparing the dinner continued upto the time I came? Could it be that As I entered, friend ended the preparation? 3. In 'By midnight, I will be home for 3 hours'. Is it correct? I mean does it mean I will be home for three hours for the time extending upto midnight.

Comment: @shikhaji - Please consider asking a new question if you need more guidance. Here is a link to help you find an answer: ["Now" vs "by now"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24249/37009).